# Sphinx Search Reindex

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I have set up Sphinx on a XAMPP server and now I wan't to set it up on a Linux server. How can I obtain this? Also, how can i automatically reindex after a given amount of time? I searched for a tutorial but all I found was explaining how to set up the first index, nothing about reindexing and setting up a cronjob or something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add into your system this command as a scheduler job:

```
indexer --all --rotate
```

In Linux, you can use `cron`. In Windows - standard scheduler with bat file with this Windows command analog.

Comment: Something like this */5 * * * * /home/search/bin indexer delta --rotate --config=/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf  ?

Comment: Like this: `*/5 * * * * root /home/search/bin/indexer delta --rotate --config=/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf` check where is your indexer (`whereis indexer` `indexer: /usr/local/bin/indexer`)

Comment: OK, and if I have on the same server different websites like this site1.example.com, site2.example.com, site3.example.com ... site6.example.com, each with it's own database. How should i set up than the Sphinx? Should i install it for each site, will i need 6 sphinx.conf files?

Comment: No, you need to create 6+ SRC and INDEX sections for every index of your sites. Than use different indexes in your site's querys.

Comment: Ok, but in the sphinx api how should i call the custom query?  Currently I have something like this. $s = new SphinxClient;
    $s->setServer("127.0.0.1", 9312);
    $s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
    $s->SetLimits(0, 10000);
    $result = $s->Query("@(" .  implode(',', $userset['fields']) . ") " . implode(' ', $userset['keywords']));

Comment: I don't know what API do you use. You need to check documentation. Sphinx has mysql-like interface: `Select id, weight() from index_name WHERE MATCH(keywords);`

Comment: Ok, I'm using the Sphinx Search Api, but i will try your suggested way. Thanky you.